# relation between two properties of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

A topological space ‎$  ‎(‎X, ‎\tau)‎‎$‎ is ‎QHC‎ (**quasi-H-‎cl‎osed**) if every open filter base has a cluster point or equivalently if every open cover has a finite subfamily whose closures cover X.

In a topological **KC-space**, every compact space is closed.

> Is every QHC space KC?or is every KC space QHC?
>
> In KC space, is closed subspace QHC?
>
> Is there any example to show The two spaces above are not related؟

Answer (score 1):

You should really try more basic examples:

Define $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the excluded point topology wrt $0$, say.

$X$ is compact so certainly QHC. But $\{0\}$ is a compact subset that is not closed. So $X$ is not KC. The cofinite topology on $\Bbb R$ also works.

$\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology is KC (even Hausdorff) but not QHC, take the cover $(-n,n), n \in \mathbb{N}$, e.g.

This also yields many other closed non-QHC subspaces like $\Bbb Z$.

So between KC and QHC there are no implicational relations.

Comment: why X with the excluded point topology wrt  0 is compact?

Comment: @adin the only neighbourhood of the excluded point is the whole space.